# Error while training with Sequential in Keras: Shapes are incompatible

Tags: keras

I am training a neural network (2 conv layers and 1 dense hidden layer) to classify hand-sign images for 24 alphabets (J and Z has no images). Using ImageDataGenerator's flow() function to create training and testing data generators. Using Keras Sequential to create the neural network model. While training, I am getting the following error:

```
model = create_model()

# Train your model
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    epochs=15,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)

Epoch 1/15
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-746fb7255d3f> in <module>()
      6 history = model.fit(train_generator,
      7                     epochs=15,
----> 8                     validation_data=validation_generator)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise


ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1790, in categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5083, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    **ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 24) are incompatible**
```

Here is the link to the colab code: [1](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BD8o8ZoJroSJYcTYV_uEh6wDtPa9sgCw?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one hot encoding for the y parameters where you define training and validation generator. So under 'train_val_generators' function change:

`y=training_labels`

into

`y=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(training_labels, x)`

and do same thing for the validation. x is the number of output neurons.